# How can I connect to mongodb using express without mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using the express framework and would like to connect to a mongodb without using mongoose, but with the native nodejs Mongodb driver. How can I do this without creating a new connection every time?

To handle get or post requests I currently open a new connection to the db for every request and close it on completion of the request. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know that you're necessarily truly opening a new connection every time. Check out https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling

Comment: but in that case if connection to db couldn't be established then out server itself will not be up.

Comment: The basic pattern still works.  I'll follow up with an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following the example from my comment, modifying it so that the app handles errors rather than failing to start the server.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var app = express();

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dbURL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test";
var db;

// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect(dbURL, function(err, database) {
  if(err) return console.error(err);

  db = database;

  // the Mongo driver recommends starting the server here 
  // because most apps *should* fail to start if they have no DB.
  // If yours is the exception, move the server startup elsewhere. 
});

// Reuse database object in request handlers
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var collection = "replicaset_mongo_client_collection";
  db.collection(collection).find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    docs.each(function(err, doc) {
      if(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
      }
      else {
        res.end();
      }
    });
  });
});

app.use(function(err, req, res){
  // handle error here.  For example, logging and 
  // returning a friendly error page
});

// Starting the app here will work, but some users 
// will get errors if the db connection process is slow.  
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
```

Comment: What if I am using mongoose?

Comment: @SudhirKaushik what if you are?  This answer is to the question "how do I do it without mongoose".

Comment: Its so awkward when you look back at your answer and feels that "I could have said it in better way". 

Anyways, my above question was sort of selfish one as I was trying to setup using mongoose. Should have asked with a different question. Nevermind

Comment: @SudhirKaushik check [this](https://codeburst.io/building-a-rest-api-using-mongo-db-75cac3403fab) out. There are tons of tutorials that use mongoose. Thanks Paul, for sharing this snippet.

Answer (score 3):

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname';

module.exports = function(callback) {
  mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, callback);
};
```

Ad this snippet in a file say connect.js and then require this file(connect.js) in your file where you are declaring your functions for http requests.

Comment: But this snippet will also make a new connection request everytime and that's something we don't want

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct way i.e to check whether the connection is established or not before making a http request.

Comment: I believe that requiring this snippet will be cached within the application and it will NOT make a new request every time.