# Why the data stored in the MongoDB is not being display in HTML file by using mustache?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mustache

I am trying to run a web application to display some data of the Database to a HTML page. The data is stored in a MongoDB database and it is displayed in the HTML page using Mustache. But, when I try to run this program, it doesn't show anything. What can be the problem? Did I forget to import something related to mustache? Am I sending data to HTML in a wrong way? All the code is available down below.

Node JS code:

```
var express = require("express"),
    consolidate =  require("consolidate"),
    MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient,
    Server = require("mongodb").Server;

var app = express();

var errMsg = "";
var name = "";

app.engine('html', consolidate.hogan);
app.set("views", "static");

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27018", { useNewUrlParser: true },  (err, db)=>{
    dbo = db.db("incidents_db");
    if(err) throw err;
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        dbo.collection("incidents").find((err, doc) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            res.render("main.html", doc);
        });


    });

    app.get("/incident", function(req, res){
        res.render("incident.html", {username: name});
    });

    app.get("/authentication", function(req, res){
        res.render("authentication.html", {errMsg: errMsg});
    });


    app.use(express.static('main'));
    app.listen(8080);
});
```

HTML code (table):

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <th class="th1">Description</th>
                <th class="th2">Address</th>
                <th class="th3">Reported by</th>
                <th >Date</th>
            </thead>
            {{#incidents}}
            <tr>
                <td class="th1">{{description}}</td>
                <td class="th2">{{address}}</td>
                <td class="th3">{{author}}</td>
                <td class="th4">{{date}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/incidents}}
  </table>
```

JSON object

```
 {"incidents":[
        {"description": "This is a example of report.", 
         "address": "5th Street", 
         "author": "Bob", 
         "date": "16/02/19"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run your code and there are a few problems right now. First of all you are trying to wrap all your express app inside the `MongoClient.connect()` callback. What you want do this probably connect to the database and initialize it first. Upon initializing you will be able to do the queries in your routes.

You can do this by initializing a variable and then assigning it the cursor.

```
var database;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27018/incidents_db", { 
    useNewUrlParser: true 
    },  
    (err, db) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    database = db;
});
```

If you need clarifications on how to do this you can check the question [How can I connect to mongodb using express without mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374842/how-can-i-connect-to-mongodb-using-express-without-mongoose)

Then you can refer to the database in your router.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    database.collection("incidents").find((err, doc) =>{
         if(err) throw err;
    res.render("main.html", {'incidents': doc });
   });
});

app.use(express.static('main'));
app.listen(8080);
```

You are setting your views directory be `static` is the case? Do you have a folder with the main.html ? If not nothing will be rendered.

In the likelihood of mongo connection failing you could try to directly pass the object to the view template and see that the values are shown as you expect them to be.

```
app.get("/incident", function(req, res){
    res.render("incident.html",  {"incidents":[
        {"description": "This is a example of report.", 
         "address": "5th Street", 
         "author": "Bob", 
         "date": "16/02/19"}]});
});
```

Comment: Now it gives an error saying that "database.collection is not a function".